# My React script won't load when I run my Node server with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, reactjs

I'm new to react and node so bear with me. I'm trying to create a simple tic tac toe game with react and socket but when I run my server I and then try to load the website it only shows the html and the react doesn't render.

I don't see any errors so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var websocket = socketio(server);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

websocket.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Tic Tac Toe</h3>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
        socket: SocketIOClient('http://localhost:3000')
    };
  }
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}/>
    );
  }

  handleClick(i){
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    });
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Board />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you including the react scripts?

Comment: The react script is in a separate file and I try to render it at 'root'. Do i need to include it somewhere else?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed it somehow when I was looking at it before :) 

Try moving these lines to the bottom of the HTML page:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>`